# Vertically align text to the top beside another text

Tags: css, html

I am having a div with various texts. I need to make the am and pm on the top.

My HTML code is-

```
<div class="agendaBlackDiv">
  <span class="agendaTimeStop">10:00</span >
  <span>a.m.</span>
  <text>-</text>
  <span class="agendaTimeStop">11:30</span>
  <span>p.m.</span>
</div>
```

Here is JSfiddle link- [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/uq39o4gr/)

Comment: That is not valid HTML. The `<div>` is never closed and the `<text>` tag is not a standard HTML tag. You should use `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

==
Hi now define your  `.text` **class** two **property** as like this

```
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uq39o4gr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css class from

```
text
{
    color:white;
}
```

to

```
text
{
    color:white;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```